# api calls are running unexpected number of times

Tags: javascript, json, api, twitch

i am working twitch tv api.api calls should me made equal to number of elemnts in streamer array.but it is call multiple times.u can see it on codepen.

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/o48wwLdf/)https://jsfiddle.net/o48wwLdf/
html

javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i;
  var streamers = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];        //streamers array
  for (i = 0; i < streamers.length; i++) {
    jsoncall(streamers[i]);                            //calling function for api calls.
  }
});

function jsoncall(stream) {                            //function for api call
  $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + stream + '?callback=?', function(data) {
    if (data.stream === null) {                       //if channel is offline display offline
      $("p").append("<p>" + stream + "                                offline</p>");
    } else {                                    //if channel is online show what is he streaming.
      $("p").append("<p>" + stream + data.stream.game + "</p>");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle so that we can have a look

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal there's a CodePen link in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$("p").append(...);
```

the content is appended to *every `<p>` element on the page*.  Since you're adding more `<p>` elements in the content, you get duplicates all over the place.

[Here's a forked version of your CodePen](http://codepen.io/Pointy/pen/BzLdYK). I added an id to the main `<p>` element. Note that appending a `<p>` to a `<p>` doesn't really make sense anyway; `<p>` elements can't contain block-level elements like other `<p>` elements. Browsers allow it however. So, the HTML:

```
<p id=main></p>
```

And the updated JavaScript:

```
function jsoncall(stream) {
  $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + stream + '?callback=?', function(data) {
    if (data.stream === null) {
      $("#main").append("<p>" + stream + "                                offline</p>");
    } else {
      $("#main").append("<p>" + stream + data.stream.game + "</p>");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Add an "id" attribute to the initial `<p>` and refer to that in the jQuery selector. See the linked CodePen in my updated answer.

Comment: That's a silly mistake, but yes, that does deserve a +1.